# android-job: Periodic once a day, DeviceIdle = true, as soon as possible

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, android-job

need some help to set up my perodic job correctly with [android-job lib](https://github.com/evernote/android-job).

I want to start a job once a day and the device is ideling. Additionally the job should start as soon as possible on day. That means in best way the job start at 00:01 AM.

And it's not that solution descriped [here](https://github.com/evernote/android-job/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-can-i-run-a-job-at-a-specific-time-once-a-day)!

Is this possible?
Can anyone give me a hint for the rigth solution?

Here is my code snippset for a Job once a day if device is idle

```
        mJobId = new JobRequest.Builder(JOBTAG)
            .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(24))
            .setPersisted(true)
            .setUpdateCurrent(true)
            .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(true)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobRequest.NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build()
            .schedule();
```

Answer (score 0):

The linked helper works, you only need to adjust it to your use case.

Note that version 1.2.0 will contain a [helper class](https://github.com/evernote/android-job/wiki/Version-1.2.0-and-Android-O#add-helper-class-to-run-jobs-daily), which should make this easier for you.